# Get all custom properties of an object

Tags: python, properties

It's clear how to set and retrieve `custom properties` from an object with python, but how do you get *all* the custom properties that were set to an object ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UI defined custom properties.**

If you mean those defined by the UI

[image]
*Example, two custom properties on default object*

[Iterate over custom properties without searching?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156481/iterate-over-custom-properties-without-searching)

Their names via `keys`

```
>>> C.object.keys()
['prop', '_RNA_UI', 'prop1']
```

or via `items` to get key, value pairs

```
>>> for k, v in C.object.items():
...     print(f'ob["{k}"] = {repr(v)}')
...     
ob["prop"] = 1.0
ob["_RNA_UI"] = <bpy id prop: owner="OBCube", name="_RNA_UI", address=0x7fa661ad48c8>
ob["prop1"] = 1.0
```

The `_RNA_UI` member holds all the info re min, max, description for layout, when not defined with a `bpy.props`. *(If defined via `bpy.props` and non default the data is saved as a custom prop of same name)*

[Finding the source for "API Defined" custom properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123669/finding-the-source-for-api-defined-custom-properties)

[When should custom-properties be used instead of 'bpy.props'?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/54038/when-should-custom-properties-be-used-instead-of-bpy-props)